# "Attempted to read/write outside of hd0" after install Lubuntu alongside Windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, lubuntu

I recently installed Lubuntu onto a 160Gb HDD, alongside Windows, which is the first two partitions (System Reserved/C:). The installation completed just fine, with no errors. It then rebooted into GRUB. I tried to boot (L)Ubuntu and I got a message similar to this:

```
attempted to read/write outside of hd0
press any key to continue...
```

Using the normal Ubuntu menu option, pressing any key causes the system to hang. However, pressing any key on the recovery mode (under Advanced Options for Ubuntu) brings me to a low-res kernel panic (lower resolution than Grub).

Booting into Windows works just fine.

I apologise if this is an ametuer mistake, but I have never had to diagnose bootloader problems in the past (Windows XP/Ubuntu a few years ago, on an older laptop, worked just fine)

Windows was installed first.

Linux - strangely - shows up as sda5/sda6 (from the live CD) when Windows only shows four partitions on the disk.

Comment: Windows usually does not see Linux partitions correctly and if sda5 & sda6 then they are logical partitions inside an extended partition. The extended partition is a primary but only acts as a container for all the logicals. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was harder than it had to be.

I added a seperate boot partition (after external advice) and reinstalled. Linux now booted, but because I moved the partitions around to fit a /boot partition, Windows no longer booted. This was to be expected, so I repaired Windows using the system recovery disk, and ran grub-update after chrooting into /dev/sda6. Now GRUB only detected Windows. At this point I gave up and used boot-repair, which advised me to reinstall GRUB2. I did, and now it works!

Comment: Small correction: I think the command is actually update-grub.